# Radgrid unable to download file using linkbutton in NestedViewtemplate

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

I'm using radgrid nestedviewttemplate to show the details of a product on row expand.I also have a linkbutton in my nestedview template which when clicked downloads the file.My code that i use for download works outside radgrid but when included in Nestedviewtemplate it fails to download.here's my code.

```
 <telerik:RadGrid ID="loggedInUserOwnResourcesRadGrid"   AutoGenerateColumns="false">
 <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="false">
 <Columns>
 <telerik:GridTemplateColumn   DataField=" Name">
 <HeaderTemplate><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonForTitleOfGridViewColumn"  
  runat="server" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="Name">Resource Name</asp:LinkButton>
 </HeaderTemplate>
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonOfAParticularName"  runat="server" Text='<%# Eval(" Name")%>'></asp:LinkButton>
  </ItemTemplate>
 </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
 </Columns>
 <NestedViewSettings >
 <ParentTableRelation>
 <telerik:GridRelationFields DetailKeyField="ID" MasterKeyField="ID"/>
 </ParentTableRelation>
 </NestedViewSettings>
 <NestedViewTemplate>
 <asp:Panel ID="NestedViewPanel"  runat="server">
 <div >
 <fieldset >
 <legend ><b>Detail Info on Resource :   <%#Eval("Name") %></b>
 </legend>

  Download File :

 <asp:LinkButton ID="filenamelinkbutton" Text='<%# Eval("Filename")%>' CommandArgument='<%# 
  Eval("PathToFile")%>'  OnCommand="filenamelinkbutton_Clicked" CommandName="filenamelinkbutton_Clicked"
  runat="server"  ToolTip="Click To Download" ForeColor="Blue"  ></asp:LinkButton>

 </fieldset>
  </div>
 </asp:Panel>
</NestedViewTemplate>
  </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>

  protected void filenamelinkbutton_Clicked(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {


        string downloadfilename = e.CommandArgument.ToString();

            try
            {
                FileInfo resourcefilepathusingfileinfo = new FileInfo("~/" + downloadfilename);
                string filename = resourcefilepathusingfileinfo.Name;
                Response.ContentType = "application/download";
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename);

                Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/" + "ClientBin/" + "Uploads/" + filename));



                HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
             //   Response.End();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { 


            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

1. If your grid ajaxify with Telerik Ajax manager.

JS

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function onRequestStart(sender, args) {
            if (args.get_eventTarget().indexOf("filenamelinkbutton") >= 0) {
                args.set_enableAjax(false);
            }
        }
    </script>
```

ASPX

```
<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server" ClientEvents-OnRequestStart="onRequestStart">
    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadGrid1">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadGrid1" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>
```

1. If your grid ajaxify with update panel.

ASPX

```
<triggers>         
     <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="filenamelinkbutton" />
</triggers>
```

OR

C#

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridNestedViewItem)
    {
        GridNestedViewItem nestedItem = (GridNestedViewItem)e.Item;
        LinkButton filenamelinkbutton = (LinkButton)nestedItem.FindControl("filenamelinkbutton");
        ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterPostBackControl(filenamelinkbutton);
    }

}
```