# Downloading functionality issue in radgrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, telerik, telerik-grid

I have a tricky question and hope I can explain it well.

**Here is my question:** I have a radgrid *FormTemplate* for Adding/Editing rows in which I have used RadAsyncUpload control for uploading files. The file is being uploaded successfully on insert and update. In addition, I have a link button configured in my radgrid view to download the files whenever needed.

**The problem is now here:** When trying to download the from radgrid view right after uploading the file, I cannot download it. Instead I need to first reload the page and then I can download the file. What could be the problem? I also used *grid.rebind()* method but this doesn't work. Below is a brief area of my code:

```
<Columns>
                        <telerik:GridButtonColumn Text="Download" HeaderText="Responsible" ItemStyle-ForeColor="Blue" CommandName="DownloadResponsibleAttachment" ColumnGroupName="Attachments"
                            ConfirmTextFields="ResponsibleAttachment" ConfirmTextFormatString="Would you like to download attachment?" HeaderStyle-Width="30px"
                            ConfirmDialogType="RadWindow" Reorderable="false" UniqueName="DownloadResponsibleAttachment" ConfirmTitle="File Download">
                        </telerik:GridButtonColumn>
                    </Columns>
                    <EditFormSettings EditFormType="Template">
                        <FormTemplate>
                            <p class="lbl" style="font: 10px verdana, arial; color: #166c92; font-weight: bold;">Responsible Attachment</p>
                            <telerik:RadAsyncUpload ID="attResponsible" runat="server" InitialFileInputsCount="1" MaxFileInputsCount="1" MaxFileSize="1048576"
                                 TargetFolder="~/Attachments" TemporaryFolder="~/Attachments" TemporaryFileExpiration="600000" ControlObjectsVisibility="None"
                                 OverwriteExistingFiles="true" ToolTip="You can only upload one file with maximum 1 MB." OnFileUploaded="attResponsible_FileUploaded" >
                            </telerik:RadAsyncUpload>

                            <div style="float:right; padding-top:20px;">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" CssClass="btn" Text='<%# (Container is GridEditFormInsertItem) ? "Insert" : "Update" %>'
                                runat="server" CommandName='<%# (Container is GridEditFormInsertItem) ? "PerformInsert" : "Update" %>'></asp:Button>&nbsp;
                            <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" CssClass="btn" Text="Cancel" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"
                                CommandName="Cancel"></asp:Button>
                        </FormTemplate>
                    </EditFormSettings>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for record purpose, I want to post this answer for the problem I had. I found a way to resolved this issue. It seemed that there was a problem with **RadAjaxManager** so I replaced it with **RadAjaxPanel** which worked perfect for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to invoke download for a file from an `AJAX-enabled control` (either placed in `RadAjaxPanel or ajaxified by RadAjaxManager`), you cannot use the normal `response.WriteFile function`.

```
Response.WriteFile("~/filename");
```

Because the `XmlHttpRequest` cannot handle this.

**EDIT:**

[Please check this link for alternative](http://www.telerik.com/forums/unable-to-download-file-using-asyncpostbacktrigger-in-radgrid)

**ASPX Code:**

```
<div>
        <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </telerik:RadScriptManager>
        <telerik:RadWindowManager ID="RadWindowManager1" runat="server">
        </telerik:RadWindowManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnItemCommand="RadGrid1_ItemCommand"
                    OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource" OnItemDataBound="RadGrid1_ItemDataBound">
                    <MasterTableView Width="950" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="ID" GridLines="None"
                        TableLayout="Auto">
                        <Columns>
                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ID" HeaderText="Emp ID" ReadOnly="true" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" UniqueName="ID" FilterControlWidth="30px" AutoPostBackOnFilter="true"
                                CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" />
                            <telerik:GridButtonColumn DataTextField="Name" ItemStyle-ForeColor="Blue" CommandName="Generate"
                                ConfirmTextFields="Name" ConfirmTextFormatString="Would you like to  {0} ACH file ?"
                                ConfirmDialogType="RadWindow" Reorderable="false" UniqueName="ButtonName" ConfirmTitle="ACH File">
                            </telerik:GridButtonColumn>
                        </Columns>
                    </MasterTableView>
                </telerik:RadGrid>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
    {
        dynamic data = new[] {
             new { ID = 1, Name ="Name_1"},
               new { ID = 2, Name = "Name_2"},
               new { ID = 3, Name = "Name_3"},
               new { ID = 4, Name = "Name_4"},
               new { ID = 5, Name = "Name_5"}
        };

        RadGrid1.DataSource = data;

    }


    protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
        {
            GridDataItem item = e.Item as GridDataItem;
            ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterPostBackControl(item["ButtonName"].Controls[0]);

        }
    }


    protected void RadGrid1_ItemCommand(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Generate")
        {
            Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename= errorLog.txt");
            Response.AddHeader("content-length", "0");
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hmm I see, I have used Response.WriteFile("~/filename"); in my code behind. what could be the alternative method to handle this issue?

Comment: I applied the same methodology you recommended but I still get an error. I am amazed that when I reload my page, I get the same error but I can then still download file.

 

The error specifically I get is as below:

Data = Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.

 

​

Thank you in advance,

M. Fawad Surosh

Comment: I applied the same thing but doesn't work. To add into my scenario, I am not using  UpdatePanel but I am using RadAjaxManager.

Comment: It has to work buddy. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: @FawadSurosh [Please check this link for RadAjaxManager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17597227/radgrid-unable-to-download-file-using-linkbutton-in-nestedviewtemplate)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74817/discussion-between-fawad-surosh-and-rahul-nikate).

Answer (score 0):

I applied a solution to reload the page any time a record is successfully inserted/updated as below:

```
protected void grid_ItemInserted(object source, GridInsertedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Exception == null)
        {
            if (Session["FileUploaded"] != null)
                Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
        }
    }
```